# Convert RGBA image to array in specific range in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an array of values in range of 1500 to 4500.
I managed to convert the data using matplotlib function. The code as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=1500, vmax=4500)
jet = plt.cm.jet
# generate 100x100 with value in range 1500-4500
original = np.random.randInt(1500,4500, (100,100))
# array in shape (100,100)
# convert the array to rgba image 
converted = jet(norm(original))
# image in shape (100,100,4)
```

How to get the original array from converted images?

Answer (score 2):

Some rounding will take place because of the limited amount of colors in the colormap, so a perfect reversal is not possible.

But you can get close by simply inverting the colormap and subsequent normalization.

Starting with some sample data:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
data = rng.integers(1500,4500, (3,3))

# array([[4051, 3410, 3033],
#        [2309, 2423, 1622],
#        [1725, 1549, 2025]], dtype=int64)
```

Which can be converted to RGBA:

```py
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=1500, vmax=4500)
cmap = mpl.colormaps["jet"].copy()

data_rgb = cmap(norm(data))
```

Converting the colormap to a lookup table, I'll drop the alpha for simplicity since this colormap doesn't use it.

```py
lut = np.zeros((256,) * 3, dtype=np.uint8)

for i in range(cmap.N):
    r,g,b,a = cmap(i)
    lut[int(r*255), int(g*255), int(b*255)] = i
```

The lookup table can then be indexed with the RGB expressed as bytes:

```py
data_rgb_byte = (data_rgb*255).astype(np.uint16)
data_inv_norm = lut[
    data_rgb_byte[:,:,0], 
    data_rgb_byte[:,:,1], 
    data_rgb_byte[:,:,2],
]/255

data_recovered = norm.inverse(data_inv_norm).data

data_recovered
# array([[4052.94117647, 3405.88235294, 3029.41176471],
#        [2311.76470588, 2417.64705882, 1617.64705882],
#        [1723.52941176, 1547.05882353, 2017.64705882]])
```

I guess the loss in accuracy relates to the range of initial normalization `(4500 - 1500 = 3000)` compared to the resolution of the colormap (`N=256`), so `3000/256 ~= 11.7`.